# How to reference objects outside of an if statement in java

Tags: java, actionlistener

I am a novice programmer trying to get a leg up before I take programming classes in college, so go easy if this is an easy fix. I am trying to once a radio button is clicked to make the current form disappear and a second form appear. Is the problem because I have it in an event listener? If so how can I get it to jump out of the listener, I tried a break statement but that only works in loops. Thanks guys.

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            File setup = new File("file/Data.txt");
            try {
                setup.createNewFile();
            } catch (IOException e2) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e2.printStackTrace();
            }
            try {
            FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(setup);
            BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(writer);
            bw.write("Trainer");
            bw.close();
            frame1.setVisible(false);
            trainerframe.setVisible(true);
            } catch (Exception e1) {
                e1.getStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: Is this  related code ? There is no if condition , in your code

Comment: Where is the `if` statement?

Comment: why you have closing bracket like this  `});`?

Comment: You really ought to try a basic Java tutorial, especially before trying to tackle graphical applications (which involve threading issues). Most likely, you're declaring the variable inside the `if` block, so it's not visible outside; if that's the case, declare it before the `if` statement.

Comment: @ user3121794 you should take these peoples advice very seriouly\]

Answer (score 0):

Well first of all you've made it really hard for somebody to grasp what you want outta your question .Never the less what you can do is  if i understood you correctly :

Take a STATIC variable and define it globally , now inside  your for loop/ listener (where ever you want to check if the radio button is clicked ) just make this boolean variable true or false and now impose that condition(boolean variable) outside your loop/listener (whatever it is) and display the page according if its true show second page else show the first page

Comment: it's ok to use class-private variables instead of statics... use static variables ONLY if you really need statics

Comment: but he need to use it inside some listener , in that case he needs the variable to be either static or final , ain’t thats the case??

Comment: Or a member variable of that listerner which is, together with final, a lot better than a static variable.

Comment: Yea but then you wont be able to change it during runtime as per the value of radio button , isn’t it.

Comment: still it's no need to declare static variables; well, as seen in his code snippet, he can acces the frame - this alone should be enough to get to the components! so it would be useful to declare the components (radiobuttuns etc.) in the same level as the frame - still no need to decalre static variables - and think of the evil purpouse if someone start a second instance!?!?!? then ALL instances would change if the action is performed